# Erase lines from Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using a template, I have managed to draw a diagram. The diagram is exactly what I desire with one exception: I want to avoid the lines that start at the title (Game Theory Lecture Notes). Even if it should be very easy, I do not seem to be able to erase them. The output is as follows:

[image]

The MWE can be seen here:

```
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\tikzset{basic/.style={text width=22em},root/.style={basic,thin,align=center,fill=white!100},level 2/.style = {basic,draw,thin,align=center,fill=white!100,text width=16em},level 3/.style = {basic,thin,align=center,fill=gray!10,text width=14em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=60mm},]
\node[root]{\textbf{\Large{Game Theory Lecture Notes}}}
child {node[level 2] (c1) {\textbf{\large{General Introduction}} \\ \small{Chapters 1 --- 2}}}
child {node[level 2] (c2) {\textbf{\large{Non-Cooperative Games}} \\ \small{Chapters 3 --- 7}}}
child {node[level 2] (c3) {\textbf{\large{Cooperative Games}} \\ \small{Chapters 8 --- 9}}}
child {node[level 2] (c4) {\textbf{\large{Advanced Topics}} \\ \small{Chapters 10 --- 12}}};

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
\node [below of = c1, yshift=-10pt] (c11) {\textbf{Choice Theory} \\\small{Chapter 1}};
\node [below of = c11, yshift=-10pt] (c12) {\textbf{Game Theory} \\\small{Chapter 2}};

\node [below of = c2, yshift=-10pt] (c21) {\textbf{Normal Form Games} \\\small{Chapter 3}};
\node [below of = c21, yshift=-10pt] (c22) {\textbf{Extensive Form Games} \\\small{Chapter 4}};
\node [below of = c22, yshift=-10pt] (c23) {\textbf{Equilibrium Concepts} \\\small{Chapter 5}};
\node [below of = c23, yshift=-10pt] (c24) {\textbf{Repeated Games} \\\small{Chapter 6}};
\node [below of = c24, yshift=-10pt] (c25) {\textbf{Incomplete Information} \\\small{Chapter 7}};

\node [below of = c3, yshift=-10pt] (c31) {\textbf{Bargaining Theory} \\\small{Chapter 8}};
\node [below of = c31, yshift=-10pt] (c32) {\textbf{Coalitional Games} \\\small{Chapter 9}};

\node [below of = c4, yshift=-10pt] (c41) {\textbf{Epistemic Game Theory} \\\small{Chapter 10}};
\node [below of = c41, yshift=-10pt] (c42) {\textbf{Lexicographic Beliefs} \\\small{Chapter 11}};
\node [below of = c42, yshift=-10pt] (c43) {\textbf{Algorithmic Game Theory} \\\small{Chapter 12}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If anybody knows how to delete those lines, I'll be very happy. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: `[level 1/.style={sibling distance=60mm, edge from parent path=}]`

Comment: @MarkWibrow Absolutely perfect. If you could just turn your comment into an answer, I'd be very happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove the lines it is necessary to change the `edge from parent` options in the `level 1` style. Setting it to empty does the trick:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=60mm, edge from parent path=}]
```